# Joomla Poll not displaying correctly in IE6 after converting template to 1.5x

Tags: joomla, internet-explorer-6

Recently I converted Joomla 1.0x template to 1.5x for a client of mine. Almost everything went smoothly, I migrated the content, menus, etc. and the website is up and running at the moment. I didn't notice at first that my Poll window is sort of broken. Polls are displaying correctly in every browser except IE6 (I know, one more crappy IE6 problem).

There's no error displaying, no modules flying all around and stuff like that :) The page body, where poll results should be displayed, are showing nothing, *nichevo*, *nada*... as if there's no content at all in there.

[Here](http://zdravzivot.com/index.php/Poll-results/Koji-na%C4%8Din-ishrane-daje-najve%C4%87e-%C5%A1anse-za-dug-i-sre%C4%87an-%C5%BEivot.html)'s the link to that page.

As you can see, it looks OK in Firefox, IE7, Safari, etc., but in IE6 - nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the `divs` in the poll are too wide for the layout. This makes the entire table jump in IE6.

You can fix it by setting a smaller width for the contentpane div

```
.contentpane {
    width:540px;
}
```